# Regular expression to match everything except two strings?

Tags: regex

Let's say I have some logs saying:

```
s3://hello/world
s3n://hello/again
```

I want to get the following result:

```
hello/world
hello/again
```

My initial idea was `((s3n:\/\/)|(s3:\/\/))` but this, of course, selects just `s3n://` and `s3://`. I need to negate (invert) this selection but it isn't as simple as it seems for strings (not characters).

How would you go about inverting this selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `^s3n?:\/\/(.*)`, which can be tried [here](https://regex101.com/r/CtQbzJ/1). Your desired string is in the 1st capturing group.

Explanation:

- **^** - Matches the start of the string.
- **s3n?** - Matches "s3" followed by an optional "n".
- **:\/\/** - Matches a colon and two forward slashes.
- **(.*)** - Matches and captures the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch what comes after the semicolon with a catch group (parentheses). To avoid catching the "s3n" itself, you can add a `?:` in the beginning of that group.

```
(?:s3n:\/\/|s3:\/\/)(.*)
```

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oak